# load uiscrollview same as uitableview

Tags: objective-c

I need to make a cell having a larger length with no of sub views and i am having a no of these cells.i added all of these cells in UIScrollview,When I scroll scrollview I want that it load just like as UITableView Loaded. Please Suggest Some Method With Code.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need not to use `UIScrollView`. I prefer having custom `UITableViewCell` which would be reused.